# ideas for speeding up a design based on abstract iterators

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

In some C++ project I'm dealing with objects that represents graphs of various nature. They all implement a common, abstract, interface, which I'll reduce to one function for this post:

```
class graph {
public:
   ...
   // Create an iterator over the successors of v
   virtual succ_iterator* succ(const vertex* v) const = 0;
   ...
};
```

The `succ_iterator` class is also an abstract class that makes it possible to iterate over the successors vertices of `v`:

```
class succ_iterator {
public:
   virtual void first() = 0;               // reset the iterator
   virtual void next() = 0;                // move to next successor
   virtual bool done() const = 0;          // no more successor left?
   virtual const vertex* dest() const = 0; // destination vertex
};
```

So a loop over all the successors of `v` in graph `g` would look like this:

```
succ_iterator* i = g->succ(v);
for (i->first(); !i->done(); i->next()) {
   // use i->dest()
}
delete i;
```

I use such a loop very often to implement graph algorithms. **Profiling the code reveal that its spending a lot of time allocating memory for these tiny iterator instances, so I'd like to hear about ideas to improve this.**

Unfortunately, my graphs can be have very different implementations, so each graph may have its own implementation of the `succ_iterator` interface.   Essentially, each class in the `graph` hierarchy has a corresponding class in the `succ_iterator` hierarchy.  For instance one graph may be implemented using `std::vector` to store adjacency lists explicitly (in that case the `succ_iterator` is a simple wrapper above `std::vector::const_iterator`), while another graph might be computed on-the-fly (in that case its `succ_iterator` instance will actually *compute* the successors as it progresses).   I don't know the nature of the graphs at compile time, so this rules out a `template`-based implementation *à la* STL.

I have thought about allowing each graph to handle a pool of `succ_iterator`. This seems to require an extra `graph::succ_release(succ_iterator*)` method to return the iterator to the pool instead of deleting it.   Most pools I have seen are done at the memory level: i.e., when you release an object, its destructor is called, but the occupied memory is retained so that the next object will be created (with an in-place constructor) in the same block.  It seems this still wastes time as the in-place constructor will have to setup a virtual-table pointer that is the same as that of the previous object.   I think in such a pool I should replace `delete`+`new` by a `recycle()` method that has the same prototype as the constructor.   As the code base is quite large, and this requires an interface change, **I'd like to hear about other design ideas or possible improvements** before I implement this.

Edit: I don't use threads.

Comment: Step 1: try changing your implementation of `malloc`. Most `new` implementations are barebone calls to `malloc` under the hood, so switching to `jemalloc` or `tcmalloc` which were optimized for speed could yield the necessary boost without even touching your program.

Comment: Thanks for these pointers.  I'll look into these.  So far I haven't found any benchmark comparing jemalloc, tcmalloc, and glibc's malloc for single-threaded application.  Do you know of any?

Comment: unfortunately no. However one of the highlight of the [Redis 2.4 release](http://antirez.com/post/everything-about-redis-24.html) was switching from glibc to jemalloc; and Redis is single-threaded (mostly).

Answer (score 0):

You could cache the succ_iterators per graph instance and lookup and reuse them when needed?

```
//static or member:
std::map<graph*,succ_iterator*> graph_iterator_cache;
```

But I don't know if you have threadsafety issues.

Comment: I don't use any thread (at least for now).  I'm not sure I understand you suggestion: the above map would associate only one iterator to each graph.  I need to be able to use several iterators.  Typically, a DFS can be implemented using a stack of iterators (each iterator representing an edge in the set of outgoing edges of a vertex).   Sometimes I even need two iterators on the successors of the same vertex but looking at different edges (this rules out an implementation were all iterators would be preallocated for each vertex).